# Printing a large list in multiple lines

Tags: python, list

Is there a good way to print a large list in multiple lines? Assume that a list has 10000 elements and by writing that to a file it goes all in a single line which is difficult for text editors to open that.

I know I can iterate over the size with a counter and print `\n` after each 1000 elements. For example:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x = 0
for i in my_list:
    if x % 5 == 0:
        print()
    print(i, end='')
    x += 1
```

prints

```
01234
56789
```

I wonder if there is a Python function for that to do that in a more efficient way.

Comment: Do the answers to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/312443/how-do-you-split-a-list-into-evenly-sized-chunks) help at all?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop over the list in chunks and print each chunk to the file:

```py
my_list = [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
chunk_size = 3
with open('myfile.txt', 'w') as f:
    for i in range(0, len(my_list), chunk_size):
        chunk = my_list[i:i+chunk_size]
        print(*chunk, file=f)
```

This results in the file content

```
0 1 2
3 4 5
6 7 8
9
```

You can change the `print()` line to format the output to your liking. To e.g. remove the spaces between the numbers, use `print(*chunk, sep='', file=f)`.

Answer (score 1):

In terms of number of lines of code, hard to beat this:

```
chunk_size = 10
result = '\n'.join(str(my_list)[i:i+chunk_size] for i in range(0, len(str(a)), chunk_size))
print(result)
```

Note that this does still print the commas.

Looking at your attempted solution:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
x = 0
for i in my_list:
    if x % 5 == 0:
        print()
    print(i, end='')
    x += 1
```

Can be improved using `enumerate`:

```
my_list = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]

for x, i in enumerate(my_list):
    if x % 5 == 0:
        print()
    print(i, end='')
```

Note that using "i" for the items here and "x" for the index is pretty gross though, since "i" is normally the index

Actually even the x%5 can be pulled into the print statement with a ternary expression:

```
for x, i in enumerate(my_list):
    print(i, end='\n' if x%5==0 else '')
```